# safety not guaranteed in C buffer calloc or malloc within a function?

Tags: c, memory

This is a question about how to have "belt and suspenders" safety within a simple bit
of C code.  The old and somewhat beaten to death issue being how to ensure that one
may move data into a buffer within some called function without worry that the heap
memory is corrupted after return. There have been a few great things written on this 
site about the topic and, at least for me, it still isn't clear where we get real 
total safety. So I wrote the following :

```
/*********************************************************************
 * The Open Group Base Specifications Issue 6
 * IEEE Std 1003.1, 2004 Edition
 *********************************************************************/
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 600

#include <ctype.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int use_buffer( const char *strin, char **strout, size_t bufsize ) {

    size_t len;
    int result = -1;

    printf ( "in use_buffer() we have address of strout = %p\n", &strout );
    printf ( "            and that contains an address of %p\n", strout );
    printf ( "           which points to a buffer address %p\n", *strout );

    /* check for null data */
    if ( ( strin == NULL ) || ( *strout == NULL ) )
        return result;

    /* check for zero length data */
    if ( strlen(strin) == 0 )
        return result;

    /* ensure we have a non-zero size buffer to write to ?
     * belt and suspenders safety here is not assured. We have
     * no way to know if the calling routine actually did 
     * allocate memory of size bufsize. 
     */
    len = strlen(strin);
    if ( bufsize < len )
        return result;

    strncpy ( *strout, strin, len );

    return len;

}

int main ( int argc, char *argv[] ) {

    char *some_buffer;
    int retval;
    size_t buflen;

    if ( argc < 2 ) { 
        printf ( "usage: %s somestring\n", argv[0] );
        return ( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    buflen = (size_t) ( 4 * 4096 );
    some_buffer = calloc( buflen, sizeof( unsigned char) );
    if ( some_buffer == NULL ) { 
        perror ( "Could not calloc a 16Kb byte buffer." );
        return ( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    printf ( "main() has a 16Kb buffer ready at address = %p\n",
                                                      &some_buffer );
    retval = use_buffer( argv[1], &some_buffer, buflen );
    if ( retval > 0 )
        printf ( "Maybe we have %i bytes copied into a buffer.\n", retval );

    free ( some_buffer );
    some_buffer = NULL; /* belt and suspenders */

    return ( EXIT_SUCCESS );

}
```

Compile and run that and I see this :

```
$ ./use_buffer "foo of the bar"
main() has a 16Kb buffer ready at address = ffffffff7ffff710
in use_buffer() we have address of strout = ffffffff7ffff630
            and that contains an address of ffffffff7ffff710
           which points to a buffer address 100101440
Maybe we have 14 bytes copied into a buffer.
```

One of those addresses really does not look right. One of those is just not the same.

Really, it is hard to know why the first three addresses are way off wildly in some other memory region whereas the last one looks to be some local heap memory perhaps?

Is the above method absolutely belt and suspenders safe? I mean that the function is going to be working with a buffer that we know has been pre-allocated and that there is no way for the function to screw it up.  I doubt that the function can call free() on the adress stored within strout.  That would be like checking into a hotel with a room key and then setting fire to the room. While standing in it. I guess it could be done .. but would be crazy.

So there are two questions here : (1) is there a way for the function to verify the allocated buffer size? Even if the method is to trigger a memory violation. And then (2) is there any safety in passing a null pointer to the function and then allowing the function to calloc/malloc the buffer as required and pass back the address ?

I suspect that (2) has been beaten to death and the answer is "safety not guaranteed". ( sidenote : damn good movie by the way. )

Consider this code bit :

```
/*********************************************************************
 * The Open Group Base Specifications Issue 6
 * IEEE Std 1003.1, 2004 Edition
 *********************************************************************/
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 600

#include <ctype.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int bad_buffer( const char *strin, char **strout ) {

    size_t len;
    int result = -1;
    char *local_buffer;

    /* check for null data */
    if ( strin == NULL )
        return result;

    /* check for zero length data */
    len = strlen(strin);
    if ( len == 0 )
        return result;

    /*
     * safety not guaranteed ?
     */
    local_buffer = calloc( len+1, sizeof( unsigned char) );

    printf ( "  in bad_buffer() we have local_buffer at = %p\n",
                                                    &local_buffer );

    strncpy ( local_buffer, strin, len );
    *strout = local_buffer;

    return len;

}

int main ( int argc, char *argv[] ) {

    char *some_buffer;
    int retval;
    size_t buflen;

    if ( argc < 2 ) { 
        printf ( "usage: %s somestring\n", argv[0] );
        return ( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    retval = bad_buffer( argv[1], &some_buffer );
    printf ( "in main() we now have some_buffer at addr %p\n", some_buffer );

    if ( retval > 0 )
        printf ( "Maybe we have %i bytes copied into a buffer.\n", retval );

    printf ( "main() says the buffer contains \"%s\"\n", some_buffer );

    free ( some_buffer ); /* really ?  main() did not allocate this !? */
    some_buffer = NULL;

    return ( EXIT_SUCCESS );

}
```

when I compile and run that I see :

```
$ ./bad_buffer foobar
  in bad_buffer() we have local_buffer at = ffffffff7ffff6b0
in main() we now have some_buffer at addr 100101330
Maybe we have 6 bytes copied into a buffer.
main() says the buffer contains "foobar"
```

Something seems spooky here. The function did the calloc and then stuffed the address of the buffer into the *address* within strout. So strout was a pointer to a pointer and so I am fine with that. What scares me is that the memory that was allocated by the function has no right or reason to be considered safe after it is done and we are back in main().

So question number (2) stands as "is there any safety in allowing the function to calloc/malloc the buffer needed?"

Comment: "safety" is guaranteed as long as your code is correct (i.e., no UB, properly checking return values, etc.).  You don't need to verify the buffer size; if you asked for N bytes and `calloc` returned a non null pointer, it worked.  Really, it worked.  What do you mean by this: *"What scares me is that the memory that was allocated by the function has no right or reason to be considered safe after it is done and we are back in main()."*

Comment: well, the memory region that was set aside only is within scope in the function bad_buffer() and once we return from that function I suspect that the heap memory is no longer valid. That region of allocated memory is no longer in scope within main().

Comment: That's not true.  It is dynamically allocated memory.  You are confusing variables with automatic storage duration with buffers allocated dynamically.  The latter is valid until you call `free` on a pointer which refers to it.

Comment: There are two code segments there. One of them I trust because I allocate the memory in main() and then call the function. The second one below I do not trust because the memory is allocated within the function. Once we return from that function why should I trust the memory region that it allocated?

Comment: @Cratylus: It's at the top of `use_buffer`.  OP, there is no guarantee that you will always receive an address to a dynamically allocated buffer which is near previously allocated buffers.  You have a pointer to a pointer.  The address of *the pointer itself* is often very different than the address of *what it refers to*

Comment: Because that's how it works.  You only *distrust* because you don't *understand* how the language works.  You don't understand the difference between automatic storage duration and dynamic allocation.

Comment: You seem to be confusing three memory areas with your `%p` prints: stack (local variables), heap (`malloc`/`calloc` returned pointers) and values of pointers in `argv[]` (I think it's OS and even compiler dependent, where these arguments actually reside in the program address space).

Comment: comment : I was hoping to hear from someone that could explain, or even make a good guess, at why the memory addresses are so wildly different in the output.

Comment: If I do `char *p = malloc(size)`, `p` is allocated with automatic storage duration and, in practice, `&p` will be an address somewhere on the stack.  The *value* of `p` is an address to a dynamically allocated buffer (in practice, on the heap).  This is why they are different. However, no explanation is required; you are never, not once, given any sort of guarantee by the language that addresses of dynamically allocated buffers should be within some small distance of one another.

Comment: To Ed S.  I agree fully. The language doesn't bother me to much. It is the implementation and the memory handling that bothers me because there has been so much written on this topic. I felt an example case that uses two methods would illustrate the confusion.

Comment: Your premise is wrong though.  Again, the address *of the pointer itself* will likely *not* be anywhere near the addres which is its *value*.  They are two completely separate things.  If I'm the compiler I say "oh, I need to allocate a pointer in this function.  Cool, I'll put it on the stack.  Oh, it is initialized with the return value of `malloc`.  `malloc` will find an open spot at runtime and return an address to it.  That will be the pointer's *value*".  `malloc` has nothing to do with where the *pointer itself* is stored, only with initializing it with a *value*.

Comment: just to be super clear. Pedantic and even tiresome and I do apologize, I do. Are you ( Ed S. ) saying that both of the methods above are fully safe and that memory allocated will not be violated after the return back to main()?

Comment: @paullanken: I haven't looks at your code in such detail to prove that it is correct in every regard. However, a simpler example would be this:  `char *alloc_buf(size_t size) { char *ret = malloc(size); return ret; }`  I added the variable to make things more clear.  A copy of the pointer will be returned from the function.  The memory that it *refers to* will be valid until `free` is called.  Dynamically allocated memory is not scoped, only locals are, which is why returning the address of a local leads to UB.

Comment: Dynamically allocated memory is not scoped? *beauty*  Did NOT know that.  OKay.  This saves me a pile of worry.  You're awesome. So a function can go ahead and calloc/malloc so long as the pointer returned is stored into a scope safe pointer in main(). Thus a pointer to pointer is needed in the call. Safety is guaranteed.

Comment: @paullanken: Yes.  If buffers allocated dynamically were scoped then there would be no such thing as a memory leak (of course, prgramming in C would become much more difficult as well.  How would you share memory without making large copies all over the place?) When you pass a pointer to or from a function a copy is made (everything in C is passed by value).  The value of the pointer, i.e., what it refers to, is of course unchanged, but the pointer itself is a copy.

Comment: last minor thing on my mind .. what do you mean when you say "UB" ?

Comment: `strncpy ( *strout, strin, len );` is plain wrong.  (it relies on the target being initialised with NULs) strncpy() considered harmfull... UPDATE: I see it is initialised by7 calloc() still bad style, IMHO

Comment: local_buffer = calloc( len+1, sizeof( unsigned char) );  There I used an extra byte and calloc does zero fill the memory. Bad style? I thought I was being extra safe. Perhaps I should do char *nulhere = local_buffer + len + 1 and then nulhere = '\0' ?? Or similar ?

Comment: If you are sure of the correct size (and you are) , just use strcpy(), (or memcpy() + put the NUL there manually). Trusting on the NUL already being there is just a bad habit, IMHO.

Comment: to wildplasser : good pointer. I was perhaps taking advantage of the calloc zero fill feature but as a rule, strncpy should be avoided *unless* I am copying a truncated string into the middle of a destination string. In which case the nul would not be desired.

Comment: I seldomly have the need to copy a sting to the middle of another string. If I would, I'd use memcpy(). Remember: `strncpy(dst,src,len)` always touches `len` bytes. If the actual length of the `src` happens to be smaller than that, it pads the rest with NULs. Strncpy() is rarely needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ ./use_buffer "foo of the bar"
main() has a 16Kb buffer ready at address = ffffffff7ffff710
in use_buffer() we have address of strout = ffffffff7ffff630
            and that contains an address of ffffffff7ffff710
           which points to a buffer address 100101440
Maybe we have 14 bytes copied into a buffer.
```

Here 3 first values are in stack. Looking at your code, the middle one is actually address of the local argument at that function, while 1st and 3rd are addresses of local variables in `main()`. Note how stack grows down, so it's positioned at a high address, and called function arguments are lower than variables of the calling function.

4rd value is then something of a special case, because it's address of an `argv` string. Those strings are either global variables (in their own section of program address space), or they can even be at OS specific special addresses not near anything else.

---

```
$ ./bad_buffer foobar
  in bad_buffer() we have local_buffer at = ffffffff7ffff6b0
in main() we now have some_buffer at addr 100101330
Maybe we have 6 bytes copied into a buffer.
main() says the buffer contains "foobar"
```

And here again, first address is in stack, address of local variable in a function. 2nd address is memory in heap, *value* of a pointer in `main()`.

---

And yes, at a glance your code is safe. You seem to be confusing pointer value with address of the pointer variable. Consider this:

```
char *p1 = malloc(10);
char *p2 = p1;
printf("%p %p %p %p\n", &p1, &p2, p1, p2);
```

Above will print something like

```
ffffffff7ffff710 ffffffff7ffff702 100101440 100101440
```

First is address of variable `p1`, which is local variable here and in stack. 2nd is adddress of `p2`, also local variable and in stack. Then two last address as return value of `malloc` call, assigned to `p1` and copied to `p2`. That allocated block will remain until you `free` it, no matter how many times you pass the address around, or even if you lose the address (in which case you have memory leak). When you `free` it, any pointers which still point to that area become dangling pointers, and should not be dereferenced.

Comment: Awesome. I think the real crux of the issue is that the memory region is in fact safe and stays that way until I call free() on a pointer that refers to it. It does not matter if the calloc was done in main() or in some function. Am I correct here?

Comment: Added two more sections to the answer, one specifically covering the heap allocation.

Comment: brilliant stuff. I get it. I was worried, wrongly, that the memory region allocated was somehow temporary and only in scope within the function that did the calloc. Wrong. Now I see and have been educated and am thankful for this site and great folks like you and Ed S.

Comment: Thanks. And yeah, returning address of a local variable is a very common mistake made by inexperienced programmers with C (and C++ especially, where there's extra danger of returning reference to local variable), so it really is something to pay attention to.

Answer (score 3):

> One of those addresses really does not look right. One of those is
>   just not the same.
>
> Really, it is hard to know why the first three addresses are way off
>   wildly in some other memory region whereas the last one looks to be
>   some local heap memory perhaps?

`some_buffer` (or its alias `strout`) is a local variable stored in the **stack** of `main` and is pointing to an address in the **heap**. So they are addresses of different memory areas